# Setup Sub-Domain on same server [shared windows hosting]

Tags: windows, hosting, subdomain

I have a domain name registered lets say example.com. My hosting plan with (m6.net) allows me to setup unlimited domains and sub-domains. Now I want to setup test.example.com

I set it up using control panel provided by hosting company. I make the necessary entries (almost nothing except the sub-domain name and choosing main domain), create a website. Now when I try to access test.example.com chrome says that it is not able to find and instead suggests to go to example.com.

I had raised the tickets with hosting company, at first they said that I have not registered example.com anywhere and am only hosting website with that name on their servers (unfortunately it is registered with another registrar). I sent them the registration details and then they said that some changes were made to DNS settings and I will get test.example.com shortly. But it is still the same story.

Now my question is: Do I need to make any changes with my registrar to enable sub-domain on my top-level domain or do I need to setup the DNS in some different way so that people are able to find sub-domain? I am totalyl at loss...

Comment: It sounds like you need a _competent_ web hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work this through with your web host.  We can't speak to specifics about each shared host or DNS host!

---

Typically you will either host your DNS records with the web host or keep them separate.

If separate you will need to add the corresponding DNS records with the DNS host as well as configure the required records with your web host so they respond to incoming requests for that domain.  You should not change anything with your registrar unless they also happen to host your DNS records.

Be patient, DNS records can take time to propogate depending on where you live and where your DNS lives.

Comment: thanks Brent, I figured out that we need to put A record for sub-domain with our DNS provider.